# Parallel loops with the dataframe package in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am trying to run operations in parallel that read a file, perform operations on it and write a results file. The code looks like this

```
files = ["50000.csv","100000.csv","150000.csv","200000.csv","250000.csv"]
addprocs(3)
@parallel for j = 1:5
  tic()
  using DataFrames
  using Base.Dates
  df = load_data(files[j])
  v = calculate_things_per_row(df)
  name = string("file",j)
  writetable(name,v)
  toc()
end
```

This works without the @parallel,  but with it it just kind of does nothing. Meaning, executing this file in the terminal returns nothing and no files are created. Does anybody have an idea what the problem is here? Tried on both Windows and Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 4):

There are other issues with the code, but I believe you will be able to tinker and resolve it once your code work, so let me focus on the intended problem here...

Please refer to [Parallel Computing](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/parallel-computing/) in Julialang's doc. I shall quote from it:-

> For example, the following code will not work as intended:

```
a = zeros(100000)
@parallel for i=1:100000
   a[i] = i
end
```

> However, this code will not initialize all of `a`, since each process will have a separate copy of it. Parallel for loops like these must be avoided. Fortunately, distributed arrays can be used to get around this limitation (see the DistributedArrays.jl package).

For your example, the variable `name` declared in the for loop is ok when there is no `@parallel`, but when we add it in, each of the `name` becomes local to the worker, and so will not be sent back to the calling process.

There are some ways to resolve this. The least changes to your code will be to return the result table for each worker instead, and do merging outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Actually problem is that `@parallel for` loop is creates list of worker threads and ends **immediately**, without waiting for iterations completion. So with `@parallel` your loop finishes immediately, while workers threads do processing in background.

If you wish to wait for iteration completion at the end of the loop, you need use `@sync`:

```
@sync @parallel for j = 1:5
    # loop body here
end
```

And as mentioned in previous answer, please refer to [Parallel Computing](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/parallel-computing/#parallel-map-and-loops) in Julialang's doc, since `@parallel for` loops are dramatically different from usual loops.